# How to fix my Arraylist and set it in my ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i'm having the problem of putting the values from the Firestore to my list view. I watched tutorials on Youtube to know how this works but unfortunately nothing is working.

I have tried anything but nothing works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> doctors =new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView txt;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference noteRef = db.collection("Doctors");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db.collection("Doctors")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                doctors.add(document.getId());


                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, doctors);

        txt = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.gg1);
        txt.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting ?

Comment: None, it's just not displaying on my list view but whenever i specify an specific array like String[] disp = {"Hello","World}; it works.

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint `  doctors.add(document.getId());` to see if you're actually getting data ?

Comment: Tried to print it using Toast. it displays the data but when i tried to put it in my ArrayAdapter it displays nothing, it became an empty list or something, i really have no idea.

Comment: @Ezekiel Refrace your question or add you comment about the list not displaying listitems.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new 
ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, doctors);

txt.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

to onComplete after the for loop is finished. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this edited code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> doctors =new ArrayList<String>();
ListView txt;

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference noteRef = db.collection("Doctors");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, doctors);

    txt = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.gg1);

    db.collection("Doctors")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            doctors.add(document.getId());


                        }
                   txt.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but everytime you make some changes, you should also inform the adapter about those changes. It is good that you set the adapter outside the callback and inside it, just notify the adapter about the changes using the following line of code:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

P.S. Don't also forget the make your adapter a global variable:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
```