# How to refresh Listview always tabbed layout?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tabbed layout with 2 fragments:

1 - Form to register

2 - Format to view the registered documents

The second tab has a `ListView` data, and his code to get data is:

```java
public class PatologiaListaFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentLista";
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference usuarios;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patologias_lista, container, false);

    usuarios = db.collection("Usuarios").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString()).collection("Doencas");

    ArrayList<Doenca> doencaArrayList = new ArrayList<Doenca>();

        usuarios.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                       Doenca doenca = document.toObject(Doenca.class);
                        doencaArrayList.add(doenca); // add data to arraylist adapter
                        Log.i("Lets moving", doencaArrayList.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listViewCadastro);
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new DoencaAdapter(getActivity(), doencaArrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //arrayadapter set

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Erro ao puxar documentos", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    return root;
    }

}
```

I receive data to `ListView` adapter from my server on Firebase, when I close and open the app, the listview refresh, but, I need that whenever you move to one side and forward(before tab), you need to update the ListView adapter.

Is possible? Or I need to migrate to `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need that whenever you move to one side and forward(before tab), you need to update the ListView adapter.

As I understand you need to get data in real-time. In this case, you should use a real-time listener. According to official documentation regarding [listen to 
multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection):

> As with documents, you can use `onSnapshot()` instead of `get()` to listen to the results of a query. This creates a query snapshot.

So the key for adding the real-time feature is the use of Query's [addSnapshotListener(EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) method:

> Starts listening to this query.

Regarding the use of a `RecyclerView`, it's up to you decide which is better for you. It's true that a `RecyclerView` offers more features but you can check these answers out:

- [Android Recyclerview vs ListView with Viewholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525112/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-with-viewholder)

Comment: ```ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listViewCadastro);
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new DoencaAdapter(getActivity(), doencaArrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //arrayadapter set```

This methods must be change too?

Comment: Inside the callback, you should notify the adapter. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127984/how-to-fix-my-arraylist-and-set-it-in-my-listview/57131519#57131519)** out.